# Angular ng-repeat item filter

Tags: angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I have an array of menu items that I am trying to display based on user permissions. Each menu item has a property `group` which is a group number the menu item belongs to. Items should be shown in ascending group number and after each group there should be a divider indicating a separation between the groups.

```
<li ng-repeat="item in (sortedItems = (navSidebar.menu.items | orderBy:['group','position','title']))" data-ng-if="item.show()">
    <span>{{item.title}}</span>
    <hr ng-show="item.group !== sortedItems[$index+1].group && !!sortedItems[$index+1].group && item.group !== 0">
</li>
```

So first I am sorting the items by group and then within each group, by their position. Then I have `sortedItems` as a new array. Then I basically show the divider if an items group number is different than the next item.

`item.show()` method on each item returns a boolean which shows/hides the item based on a users permissions. The problem I am facing is that the divider logic is always checking the next item's group number but the next item is not visible to some user's. So, it throws off the logic and the divider's are not consistent.

Yes, I know the array can be injected into the view with all the logic done in the controller already. I am strictly told to do this in the view however.

Any advice on how to accomplish this? First time posting here.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example] (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).